# Is sort a, b, c equivalent to sort c; sort b; sort a?

Tags: c++, sql, excel, ms-access, dataset

In C++, I have to implement an "Excel/Access-like" (quote) query-builder to allow custom sorting of a dataset. If you sort by columns A, B and C in Excel using the query builder or "ORDER BY a, b, c" in SQL, you get all the As in order, all the Bs within each group of identical As in order, and all the Cs within each group of identical Bs in order, which is what most people understand by "sort/order by a, b, c". This seems to be the same as doing "sort by c", then "sort by b", then "sort by a" - ie. sorting individually on each column in reverse order - as long as you use stable_sort. Which is how I've implemented it in my program. User says "sort by a, b, c", program does stable_sort by c, stable_sort by b, stable_sort by a - same result, with all the datasets I've used so far. My question is, is this a well-known equivalence that holds true for any dataset (**provided a stable sort algorithm is used**) and any combination of columns, and is there even a mathematical proof for it? I have not found any such proof via Google or other means (asking programmers, statisticians and mathematicians) so far.

Comment: I don't know about equivalence, but for performance your proposed scheme sounds worse if I understand you correctly.  It sounds like you always sort the _entire_ dataset for each ordering.  This should be the worst case with the "forward" ordering where the entire dataset is sorted for the first ordering and only subsets of the dataset are sorted with each additional ordering.

Comment: Agreed that the performance is not ideal - although in terms of time spent coding, it is perhaps more efficient! As the datasets the application needs to deal with are 10,000 rows max, usually much less, the hardware is modern and the app is user-driven, it seems pragmatic to do it this way when there are deadlines to meet and coding time could be spent elsewhere - which is why I was wondering if this way of doing it would suffice. I think it does: it does what the user wants, and the performance hit is negligible. But if speed was mission-critical, it is not the best way, absolutely.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is correct. The "proof" is in the very definition of the stable sort:

> A sorting algorithm is stable if whenever there are two records R and S with the same key, and R appears before S in the original list, then R will always appear before S in the sorted list.

Consider your algorithm of implementing "sort by `a`, then by `b`" by sorting on `b` and then sorting on `a`. The first sort (on `b`) leaves all records with lower `b` ahead of records with higher `b` - by virtue of being a sort algorithm (stability is *not* a requirement for the first sort).

The second sort (on `a`) must pay attention to `b` only when `a`s are the same. By virtue of being *stable*, this sort leaves records with identical `a`s in the same order that they were before the sort - namely, ordered by `b`. This is precisely what you are achieving when you sort by `a`, then by `b`.

The same proof can be extended to sorting on more than two keys by observing that adding more sorting steps keeps the results of the prior steps in the original order, which is precisely the order that we want to have within the equality groups of the keys with higher sorting priority.